# WPF - Custom Window with custom DefaultStyleKey loses FocusVisualStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I've created a custom Window overriding it's *DefaultStyleKey* but I'm losing the *FocusVisualStyle* of all the controls that are contained inside of the window. Even  a custom *FocusVisualStyle* is not working. What am I missing here?

Here's how I override the *DefaultStyleKey* in the static ctor of the *CustomWindow* class:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( CustomWindow ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( CustomWindow ) ) );
```

Here's the default style defined in the *generic.xaml*:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
               <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Next step is to change the base type of the *MainWindow* to *CustomWindow* and add two buttons. While using the *Tab* key to navigate, no focus rectangle is showing up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place your `ContentPresenter` inside an `AdornerDecorator` like this:

```
<AdornerDecorator>
    <ContentPresenter/>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

It is the adorner decorator that is rendering all the focus rectangles.

When things aren't working you can look at the default control templates.  Then you try their template and your template and figure out why one works and the other doesn't!

I looked up `Window` and it looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Window}"
       TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Window.ResizeMode"
                 Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplateKey}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```